# Import function from other file in python

Tags: python, import

In `otsu.py` I have:

```
 def Hello(n):
    print "Hello",n
 print "abc"
 exit()
```

In `another.py`

```
from otsu import Hello
Hello(5)
```

When I run `python another.py`, the output is `abc`, not `Hello, 5`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would expect to get both `abc` *and* `Hello, 5`. Are you sure you're getting the right import?

Comment: You may have an `otsu.pyc` or `otsu.pyo` file in the directory with old code in it

Comment: It's working absolutely fine for me. Try `from otsu import *`

Comment: @JonathanDavies wild card imports are generally **not** recommended, as they clutter the namespace and make the code much harder to follow (or even, in the worst cases, break the code by shadowing other names).

Comment: I added the `exit()` after, but it turns out that was causing the problem. I didn't know that it would exit from the main program as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you don't have any stale `.pyc` or `.pyo` files in the directory. Or if you're using Python 3 then remove the `__pycache__` directory just to be sure. This is likely the problem.

In `another.py`, running `from otsu import Hello` should print `abc`. Then running `Hello(5)` will produce `Hello 5`. So your output will look like:

```
abc
Hello 5
```

I just ran this to confirm and it worked as expected.